# How can I add the Page control for UIScrollview with UIImageview in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

How can I add the **Page control** for `UIScrollView` with `UIImageView` in iOS. If I selected certain page control bullets means I want to move the selected image. If I move image means my pagecontrol bullets also want to move in `UIScrollView` .

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"Welcome to Home Page");
    [super viewDidLoad];

   // self.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-image.png"]];

    UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-image.png"];
    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img]];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}



- (void)loadView {


    CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];
    scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1400, 100);

    UIImageView *tempImageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sti01.png"]];
    tempImageView2.frame=CGRectMake(10, 60, 200, 200);
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView2];


    UIImageView *tempImageView3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sti02.png"]];
    tempImageView3.frame=CGRectMake(240, 60, 200, 200);
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView3];

    UIImageView *tempImageView4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sti03.png"]];
    tempImageView4.frame=CGRectMake(470, 60, 200, 200);
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView4];

    UIImageView *tempImageView5 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sti04.png"]];
    tempImageView5.frame=CGRectMake(700, 60, 200, 200);
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView5];


    UIImageView *tempImageView6 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sti05.png"]];
    tempImageView6.frame=CGRectMake(930, 60, 200, 200);
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView6];

    UIImageView *tempImageView7 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sti06.png"]];
    tempImageView7.frame=CGRectMake(1160, 60, 200, 200);
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView7];



    self.view=scrollView;
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView2];
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView3];
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView4];
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView5];
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView6];
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView7];

    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(22, 100, 1800, 500);
   // [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTest:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
    [scrollView addSubview:btn];


}


- (IBAction)buttonTest:(id)sender {
    MSDescriptionpage *aSecondPageController = [[MSDescriptionpage  alloc] initWithNibName:@"MSDescriptionpage" bundle:nil];        
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:aSecondPageController animated:YES];        
    [aSecondPageController release];

}
```

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Comment: this is for iphone.But i want to do for ipad.

Comment: Hi nikhil for this code how to pass image dynamically to next page using uibutton...

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same , what I did is I used two view controller (page view controller for page swipe ) and main view controller with `UIImage` views and you can add scroll view with images in  this ..
**these in page VC 
inside did load**

```
  [pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers  
                             direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse  
                              animated:NO 
                            completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:pageController];
    [[self view] addSubview:[pageController view]];
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *gR in pageController.gestureRecognizers) {
        gR.delegate = self;
    }
    [pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];}
```

These to call another vc

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:
(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:
(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in pageController.gestureRecognizers) {
        if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
            recognizer.enabled = NO;
        }
    }
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:
                        (MainViewController *)viewController];
    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: okay if this is helpful you can vote up .. and if your problem is solved you can check my answer correct..